# Convert 2D string array from ASP hidden field to multidimensional array in c#

Tags: c#

How can i convert this `string` from asp hidden filed

```
 "[['Q458','','100','85'],['Q459','TS','90','65'],['Q460','','80','15']]"
```

to two dimensional array in `C#`

i have tried `.ToArray()` and didn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try deserializing using `JavaScriptSerializer`:

```
var arr = hiddenField.Value;
//"[['Q458','','100','85'],['Q459','TS','90','65'],['Q460','','80','15']]" ;

var ser = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
var strArray = ser.Deserialize<string[][]>(arr);
```

Array is now 2D string Array with values like:

```
'Q458','','100','85'
'Q459','TS','90','65'
'Q460','','80','15'
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a String.Split() method to create the first level of arrays, then go through that array and call Split() again.

Your first delimiter is `],[` and the second one is just `,`.

You will have to remove the initial `[` and the final one manually `]` in all arrays (both levels).

Comment: @MinaGabriel yes there is using deserialization.

Comment: That is a programmatic way. A non programmatic way would be to require the intervention of a person...